# How does magnetism affect temperature?

Tags: magnetic-fields, temperature

I read an [article](https://www.hsisensing.com/temperature-affect-magnetism/#:%7E:text=Temperature%20affects%20magnetism%20by%20either,faster%20and%20more%20sporadic%20rate.) about how temperature affects magnetism.

> Temperature affects magnetism by either strengthening or weakening a
> magnet’s attractive force. A magnet subjected to heat experiences a
> reduction in its magnetic field as the particles within the magnet are
> moving at an increasingly faster and more sporadic rate. This jumbling
> confuses and misaligns the magnetic domains, causing the magnetism to
> decrease.  Conversely, when the same magnet is exposed to low
> temperatures, its magnetic property is enhanced and the strength
> increases.

But does it happens the other way around? Will the temperature of an object placed into a magnetic field be affected by the magnetic field?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the inverse of the process that you mentioned, but magnetism does affect the heat capacity of materials through the [magnetocaloric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration). When a suitable material is in an external magnetic field, its magnetic domains align with that field. After the material is removed from the field, the domains will become disordered. This involves transfer of internal energy from other modes into reorienting the dipoles. Consequently, the mean energy per mode will decrease and hence the temperature of the material decreases.

Answer (score 0):

Eddy currents (  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current ) produced in nearby conductive material by magnetic flux can produce heat, but a stationary non fluxing magnetic field will not change temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/magnetism-confirmed-to-control-the-flow-of-heat/#:~:text=The%20magnetic%20field%20shifts%20those,but%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20very%20surprising%E2%80%9D](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/magnetism-confirmed-to-control-the-flow-of-heat/#:%7E:text=The%20magnetic%20field%20shifts%20those,but%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20very%20surprising%E2%80%9D).
Yes, heat and sound can be manipulated through the use of magnets, although to a limited extent currently.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/402172)